# ¿Como puedo obtener los datos y seccionados por mes a partir de un rango de fechas en MYsql?

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema, tengo una serie de datos que debo de obtener pero estos los debo de seccionar por mes, por ejemplo tengo 5 articulos que se vendieron en mayo, y 10 en el mes de abril, pero esto se debe de seccionar por meses segun la fecha que especifique el usuario.

Comment: Hola @JonathanRodriguezHernandez, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. En cuanto a tu pregunta, está bastante incompleta. ¿Qué datos debes obtener? ¿Cuáles son las tablas implicadas? ¿Y sus estructuras? ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: buenos tarde, si quiere tener una ayudad con la base de datos, lo minimos que necesitamos son los nombre de los campos y el tipo de dato, asi le podemos ayudad

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te ayudará a realizar tu consulta.

```
SELECT year(arti_fecha) as anio, month(arti_fecha) as mes, count(*)  as cant
FROM articulos
GROUP BY  year(arti_fecha), month(arti_fecha)
```

Resultado de la consulta:

```
| anio | mes | cant |
  2018    2       43
  2018    3       13
  2018    4       84
  2018    5       79
```

Podrías agregar enla sentencia WHERE si deseas filtrarlo por algun cliente, sucursal o vendedor

Comment: gracias bro, ya lo resolvi hice un calculo de fechas y quedo listo